# How to filter specific lesson id in learndash using Elementor Lesson List widget

Tags: wordpress, elementor, learndash

This is my code,
I put it in Buddyboss custom javacript code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Delay execution until LearnDash content is loaded
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        // Replace the selector with the actual class or ID of your Elementor lesson list
        var lessonList = $('#ld-course-list-content-9f3deeb6159f0f2a6b15e0706ecf8794');

        // Replace 'data-learndash-lesson-id' with the actual data attribute that stores LearnDash lesson ID
        var lessonIdAttribute = '69';

        // Sort lessons based on the LearnDash lesson ID in ascending order
        lessonList.children().sort(function(a, b) {
            var lessonIdA = parseInt($(a).attr(lessonIdAttribute));
            var lessonIdB = parseInt($(b).attr(lessonIdAttribute));

            return lessonIdA - lessonIdB;
        }).appendTo(lessonList);

        // Hide all lessons initially
        lessonList.find('[' + lessonIdAttribute + ']').hide();

        // Replace with an array of specific LearnDash lesson IDs you want to filter
        var targetLessonIds = ['5194', '5195', '5199', '5205', '4307', '4294', '5207', '5203', '5201', '5197'];

        // Show only the lessons with the specified LearnDash lesson IDs
        $.each(targetLessonIds, function(index, lessonId) {
            var lessonElement = lessonList.find('[' + lessonIdAttribute + '="' + lessonId + '"]');
            lessonElement.show();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Supposedly it should follow this list
[image]

What happened the display is not showing the right order.

This is the current display right now.
[image]

Please help me on this.

Thank you